# Abracon OCXO variable frequency

Tags: oscillator

I have bought "AOCJY2-5-100.000Mhz-E-SW" OCXO which datasheet is available [here](https://abracon.com/Precisiontiming/AOCJY2.pdf).

I use [this circuit](https://abracon.com/Support/AppsManuals/Oscillators/AOCJY%20Vref%20App%20Note.pdf) to change the output frequency with a 10K variable resistor. However, by changing the value of the variable resistor the output frequency is fixed (I need to have an 80Mhz oscillator).
What is my mistake?

Answer (score 4):

Notice the spec for "frequency pull range".

Voltage at the control oin is only able to tune the frequency by a few hundred ppb, not by 20% that your application needs.

If you want to use this device type in your application, you'll need to buy one with center frequency of 80 MHz. Then you can use the control pin to compensate for small errors in the oscillator frequency,  not to make gross changes in the frequency.

If you really want a part adjustable between 100 and 80 MHz, you can probably find one. But it will most likely be sold as a VCO (voltage controlled oscillator) rather than an OCXO. And the high adjustment range will come at the expense of higher phase noise and drift due to temperature and aging.

Comment: Also, Parisa, are you even sure your use case calls for an OCXO? That thing is **way** more exact in frequency than any adjustable resistor could ever be (by easily a factor of 10,000,000), so what you want to do and what you're using doesn't sound like a match, at all.

Comment: Hello, I am really appreciative of your response. It means that I need a VCO or VCXO instead of OCXO. I need to create a resonable, affordable, simple with acceptable phase noise oscillator for my own applications.

Comment: @Parisa, A VCXO might have a few hundred ppm pulling range. If you need the phase noise of a VCXO you'll still need to pick one at your nominal operating frequency. If you need 20% pulling, it's going to be a VCO.

Comment: Thank you so much, Is there any VCO with pushing .1 MHz/V that you can suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You only misunderstood ...
 "The AOCJY series of Oven Controlled Crystal Oscillators are designed to facilitate reference frequencies
from 10.00MHz to 100MHz carrier."  .. to mean that was done with a Pot but they dont tell you its done with a PLL internally and is pre-set during order.

It is actually an ultra-stable SC cut crystal used for stratum clocks as they only drift **10 parts per billion** or about a thousand times (1k x) more stable than your average AT-cut crystal.    They typically use a 10MHz Xtal and then use a PLL to multiply the output. (using a VCO, phase detector & counter/divider)

There are lots of simple ways to get roughly 80MHz.

I know this because one of my first aerospace designs was for a little box with a 10MHz tuneable PLL using a Vectron OCXO .

If you need ultra-stability use this with a PLL to synth any frequency.

> If you don't then specify exactly what you need, input, output, tolerance error, jitter, etc. analog ? Logic ? type?

Comment: If this is a factory programmed device, why are only 6 standard frequencies specified? Factory programmed oscillators generally allow free choice of frequency with short lead-time, and crappy phase noise. I don't see anything in this datasheet to suggest they're using a PLL instead of a cut-to-order crystal (with 6 frequencies kept in stock).

Comment: 10 std f . any custom Standard Available Frequencies
10.00, 12.80, 13.00, 16.384, 20.00, 26.00, 38.40,
38.88, 40.00, 100.00 MHz

Comment: Or it's actually a traditional OCXO with the crystal cut to determine the frequency.

Comment: Considering cost and leadtime, and advantages of a cheap PLL, what advantage is there to order custom xtals when 1 will do @ThePhoton

Comment: Cost and phase noise and power.

Comment: Unless costs have changed, when I did this in '76 phase noise was excellent and PLL cost was 2% of total stress compensated OCXO  but there may be exceptions mutliplying x 10